# Cloudformation not launching WAF stack in required region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I am trying to launch a stack via AWS CloudFormation using these provided sample stack(s) for WAF:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/aws-waf-security-automations/latest/aws-waf-security-automations.template
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/community/common-attacks.json

I want to launch these stacks in us-east-1 region and I am doing so by going to this URL : 
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/new

Still when the WAF ACL and rules are created they are part of Global (Cloudfront) instead of us-east-1 region. I have tried this a few times and it works like this.

To launch these stacks in a specific region do I need to do some thing more?

Comment: This is a known limitation with CloudFormation API and this support will need to be added to this. 

This is discussed here on AWS forum as well: 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245540

Answer (score 1):

AWS now provides two CloudFormation templates. One for CloudFront (Global) and the other for ELB (Regional).

https://aws.amazon.com/answers/security/aws-waf-security-automations/